# Custom x-path, select dropdown menu using class label

Tags: selenium, select, xpath, label, traversal

I'm trying to test https://matrix.itasoftware.com/
I want to write custom XPath using label ***not using firepath.***

```
Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("id(//label[text() = 'Adults']/@for)")));
s.selectByValue("4");
```

please suggest some better way.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `custom XPath not using firepath`
? Why do you want to use label? Was this your homework? No, we are not gonna solve your homework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: @DebanjanB This is not a homework.i'm trying to self-learn some things.
I found so far with my learning
 //label[contains(.,'Adults')]
//span[contains(.,'18 to 61 years')].   but unavaible to work further to select dropdown menu as there a 2 similar nodes for same.

Comment: @AmishaDamani A WebElement/Node can be identified through an unique `xpath` or `css` in different ways. If you can mention your exact businesscase/testcase, we can help you out easily. What are your exact manual steps?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

```
Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="searchPanel-0"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select")));
s.selectByValue("4");
```